# Can we have some quality questions now?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would request users now to ask some sensible questions on the Hinduism site. Ain't sure why but some users do debate with me when I say that these types of questions should be marked off-topic.

Let me categorize the questions first which we should stop asking :

- [What is X significance in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20is)
- [What does Hinduism says about thing X](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=what%20does)

Apart from those, I've seen few questions which I feel are not at all suitable for the site and users should think twice before they ask a question that what they are really asking, for example :-

- [What do scriptures say about planet mars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3229/124) (I can make 9 definite questions out of this, also few 100 more about asking for stars and stuff)
- [Is there any provision of 'Divorce' in Hindusm?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2979/124) (No idea why community voted to reopen this)

So I don't want users to ask questions about Mars, Divorce or latest Food Dishes and so on, talk real Hinduism and not about modern things, Scriptures wont answer you that whether Pav Bhaji is tamsic, or people shouldn't divorce and so on.

**So, what I should ask?**

Read stories, read our scriptures, have doubts of why a particular thing occurred or took place? How a person died or what happened next, any confusion? Then ask a question here. Also, am not saying that questions asking for Significance or Importance etc will be closed but I think we need to go a level up now, else new users will continue these types of questions and we will never raise the bar in terms of questions quality.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.  People should look at my questions and try to emulate those:  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan?tab=questions The sort of questions I ask should be the default type of question asked on the site.  A good question should be detailed and well-researched, just like a good answer should be.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I partially(10%) agree with you. A user can ask a detailed question like yours if he is professional in this field. That means to be honest, there should be not more than 70 questions on this site. This site is for interested people, learners and professionals. There is a high probability that the interested people and learners will have many doubts, to clarify their doubts they may ask questions which sound silly to the professionals.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that users will have many doubts and they will end up asking here. if they are asking questions as explained by Mr.Alien here then let  it be. Though they are not rich and professional in content, they are valid doubts. if it is a silly doubt then I suggest mod to take action to close that post.

Comment: @Mr_Green First of all, I'm not a professional working in the field :) Second of all, I'm not saying that all the users on the site need to be as knowledgeable as me.  What I'm saying is that we need to encourage more users to put research effort into their questions.  We shouldn't ban "What does Hinduism say about X?" questions.  We should just encourage more people to write detailed and well-researched questions, and make that the standard.

Comment: hahah Pav Bhajji is tamasic? Good one. I appreciate Mr.Alien's sense of direction to lead the site into the real and awesome world. I think overall the site is doing a good job when it comes to closing off-topic questions and increasing good-quality questions. The questions that you have mentioned fall under the gray area of debatable topics, thus it is only natural to give the benefit to the OP and retain them. All the best for this site! :) Hope to see more good quality content.

Comment: @Sai Yes indeed, hence I released a progress report as you were the user who asked for the sites progress :) but again, been a moderator, I cannot make rules and apply, we need to have community inputs over them, hence users like you matters when it comes to decision making for the site. So any doubt about the scope, question, idea, put them on meta and we will have a community discussion.

Answer (score 2):

When you talk about history, it may have left the unimportant things behind unexplained which means there are no significant things to learn from the happenings there after, so am not sure how quality it would be!

When we say these scriptures are meant to teach dharmas through different examples in sruti-smriti-puranas then when we try to apply the essence drawn from it into our lives, we get practical doubts! I wish this platform can be used for that too!

Answer (score -1):

As you said "**I think we need to go a level up now**", I tried to post a more profound question about equivalence of Bhakti-yoga, Karma-yoga and Jnana-yoga.
[See here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34558/5696)

But what did I receive? A downvote! and very less views.
This shows that certain community members are themselves not much interested in profound questions.

Comment: Please don't take a couple of downvotes(DV) too seriously. A downvote can mean anything like "Your grammar needs improvement. Question is unclear, your topic is broad," etc., As many don't have time to explain, they just leave a DV. It simply means the question is unclear. So, take them as a criticism and try to look what is left in in the question/answer for improvement. When you see that, think how clearly can you explain your question. If you are not sure, peek into [chat] and ask how it can be improved. The users will help you. If you find nothing wrong even after that, just ignore them.:)