# Quality of questions and intentions of posters

Tags: discussion

The quality of questions seems to be very low and several posters seem to either be playing the fool or are non-Hindus trying to poke holes in our doctrine and popularise these misconceptions. Sadly, no one on this forum is an authority on the scriptures who can provide "Dharma Sandeha Nivrutti".

I recommend that for the time being, we limit the topics on which to ask questions. For e.g., they have to be limited to the scope of the purANAs. If we leave the scope so broad as to include veda, shat sastra, upanishad, janAchAra , dEsAchAra, superstition etc., we are doing a great disservice to this topic and our religion.

Once traction is gained on the selected topic, we can throw the gates open to an additional topic.

It may not be a bad idea to recruit established panDitas to spend some time each week to provide authentic and authoritative answers.

Lastly, we need better moderation please. Current set of  moderators, while well-meaning, are clearly out of their depth.

Comment: Anyways me and Keshav had long discussion on this and we are trying to maintain the quality of the questions. We cannot close questions if they are low quality because afterall it's still a question. Some of the basic ones infact drive in the traffic for the site so we are inspecting the questions and answers, inorder to bring a low quality post to mods attention, all you need to do is flag the post and we will take necessary actions(if required)

Answer (score 2):

Let me respond to each of your points seperately.

> The quality of questions seems to be very low[.]

I agree.  We definitely need to raise question quality.  A good question should be detailed and well-researched, just like a good answer should be.  I try to set an example of that with [my questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan?tab=questions), and we should encourage more users to ask questions like those, as opposed to "What does Hinduism say about X?" type questions.  This point has been brought up before, in [this Meta question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/321/36) for instance.

> [S]everal posters seem to either be playing the fool or are non-Hindus trying to poke holes in our doctrine and popularise these misconceptions.

First of all I think Hindus make up the vast majority of our user base, but in any case we welcome the participation of non-Hindus.  While this is a site *about* Hinduism, this is not a Hindu website.  This is a site where people can ask and answer questions about Hinduism, even if they don't believe in it.  Now spreading misconceptions is obviously not a good thing, but if you see an answer with wrong information, then suggest an edit, downvote it, comment on it, or post an answer of your own.  The best way to fight falsehoods is with truth.

> Sadly, noone on this forum is an authority on the scriptures who can provide "dharma sandeha nivrutti".

Well, whether we have "authorities" or not, we do have some users who are relatively knowledgeable about Hindu scriptures, although of course we should try to get more.

> I recommend that for the time being, we limit the topics on which to ask questions. For e.g., they have to be limited to the scope of the purANAs. If we leave the scope so broad as to include veda, shat sastra, upanishad, janAchAra , dEsAchAra, superstition etc., we are doing a great disservice to this topic and our religion.

I don't think that we should limit questions just to one scripture or category of scriptures.  But what I do think is that users should try to ask questions that are grounded in scripture.  For instance, questions that ask about a particular quote from the Vedas, Puranas, Ramayana, Mahabharata, etc.  That should help raise question quality.

> It may not be a bad idea to recruit established panDitas to spend some time each week to provide authentic and authoritative answers.

Yes, I agree.  It would be nice if we could make fliers to post in temples and other places, to encourage more experts to sign up.

> Lastly, we need better moderation please. Current set of moderators, while well-meaning, are clearly out of their depth.

Well, I've never been a moderator before, so it's certainly possible that I'm out of my depth.  But I think the moderation team as a whole is doing a great job.  But you can help the moderators do a better job; if you see an issue that could use the assistance of a moderator, just click flag button on the relevant post(s).  Together, we can make this a fantastic place to learn about Hinduism!

Comment: Appreciate your patient and considered reply. My responses:- 1. Please start closing questions which do not meet published standards. 2.Yes, anyone can ask but in the absence of authoritative refuting, falsehood will prevail. We need certain privileges even to downvote or flag. 3.Limiting question topics is one way to encourage better questions and stem the flow of falsehoods. Increase the scope as we keep getting experts onboard. 4. I applaud your optimism. I for one, am fast losing interest and hope :-(

Comment: Can you upgrade my status so I have downvote/flag privileges? Thanks.

Comment: Also, as a first step please close all questions that compare sanatana dharma to other religions. These are tiresome, serve no purpose but to undermine Hinduism and need authority on those other religions too. Some tough stances are required when our knowledge is limited.

Comment: "Please start closing questions which do not meet published standards."  Yes, at some point I would like to try to enforce higher standards of question quality, like requiring that questions show research effort and perhaps that they be grounded in scripture.  But we would need more community discussion to do that.

Comment: "
   
   
Also, as a first step please close all questions that compare sanatana dharma to other religions." I agree that questions like this are dumb: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3225/36 (On the other hand, I think questions like my question about Buddhist references to Krishna are fine: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/98/36) Why don't you create a new Meta question about religion comparison questions?

Comment: "Can you upgrade my status so I have downvote/flag privileges?"  You already have flag privileges.  You'll earn more privileges like downvoting as you get more reputation on the site by asking and answering questions among other things.  You're only 24 reputation points away from getting downvote privileges.  In the mean time you can still comment on and/or flag posts that you think are problematic.

Comment: @moonstar2001 We cannot upgrade anyone's privilege on the site, for that you need to ask question or answer questions and gain some reputation points. You are probably new to the community so learn on meta how these things work.